# How to watch an RTSP dialogue?

Tags: vlc, rtsp

I want to see a client-server dialogue during the RTSP-session, like this:

```
SETUP rtsp://...... RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: ...........
Transport: ........

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Date: Tue, Jan 15 2013 02:02:56 GMT
Transport: .......
Session: .........
```

Is it possible to watch the session, using VLC player?
If not, how to watch it the most simplest way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up wireshark and use the `rtsp` filter to see those messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling debug log before playing the stream (tools -> messages -> verbosity=2) and see if there is enough info for you. I know using libvlc its possible to have this info, not sure about the player app.